# Error en android studio al intentar levantar servicio por BroadcastReceiver android 5.1 lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo pruebas con distintos servicios y conexiones y en el `logcat` me muestra el siguiente error:

> Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView

A que se debe esto? alguien sabe?

`Servicio`:

```
public class MyIntentService extends Service {
WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
URI uri;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        uri = new URI("ws://websockethost:8080");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            mWebSocketClient.onMessage(s);
            if(s.equals("s")){
                //notificacion.....
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());

        }

    };
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    stopSelf();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myapplication.MyIntentService");
    intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Que esta realizando tu servicio? Me parece que el problema es con el adapter, agrega el código de lo que realiza este servicio por favor.

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta y agregue el código que me da el error.

Comment: Hey @DavidVillegas, no estas llenando un adapter de un ListView en tu app ?

Comment: No, estoy sencillamente probando una conexión de websocket por un servicio, y mostrar un mensaje (Toast) para verificar que se esta ejecutando, pero me da ese error... hice una variación del mismo y el error cambio a este::::: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable